# Compare two files, find the difference?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, file, compare

I have two files with the following structure.

**File A**:

```
asd
fds
sdf
asdf
```

**File B**:

```
asd
sdf
```

I want to find the difference between these two files.

This time the **result** should be **fds, asdf**.

How can I do it with c++ or linux?

Comment: Load file content into std::set<std::string>, then setA - setB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diff A B` returns

```
2d1
< fds
4d2
< asdf
```

Comment: I personally prefer the output of `diff -u`, but yes, `diff` is a very useful program that all *nix users should be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was posted by @sflee in his question. It was moved into this answer block.

**Solution**:

Here is the way I used finally, just in case that I forget this in the future. I got `A.txt` and `B.txt`:

```
sort A.txt | uniq > A2.txt
sort B.txt | uniq > B2.txt
diff A2.txt B2.txt | grep '<' > data_B2_is_missing.txt
```